# missing http(s) in <link ...> -- works?

Tags: html, css, http, networking

On The font Awesome home page, they have this link and it works without http or https

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

what does // mean then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relative link to handle both "http" and "https" versions of the page without code cahnge. `link` contains  absolute or relative url. In your case it is relative to current page:

On "HTTP" page like : `http://sample.com/home` link resolves to: `http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-aw...`

On "HTTPS" page like: `https://sample.com/home` link resolves to: `https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-aw...`